# DataTables no me encuentra los elementos dinámicos

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, crud, local-storage

Tengo un pequeño proyecto de tipo Crud(No tengo opciones de borrar y editar).
Pero tengo un problema, al ingresar un nuevo dato, creo una fila con js que luego guardo en el localstorage. Pero al querer buscarla con el buscador de datatables, esta desaparece. Para que datatables me la encuentre debo que recargar la página. Pareciera que el dato debe
estar antes de que cargué el datatables. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? Quiero que lo encuentre sin tener que recargar la página.

GitHub: https://github.com/IvanBarreraDev/Tabla

Aquí el código JS:

````
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
  let DatosDelLocalStorage= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Data"));
  DatosDelLocalStorage.forEach(function(arrayData){
    insertDataTable(arrayData);
  });
});
 form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let dataForm = new FormData(form);
  let dataFormObjt = convertObjt(dataForm);
  insertDataTable(dataFormObjt);
  guardarLocalStorage(dataFormObjt);
  form.reset();

  function convertObjt(dataForm) {
    let nombre = dataForm.get("nombre");
    let apellido = dataForm.get("apellido");
    let edad = dataForm.get("edad");
    let fecha = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
    return {
      nombre: nombre,
      apellido: apellido,
      edad: edad,
      fecha: fecha,
    };
  } 
  function guardarLocalStorage(dataFormObjt){
    let dataArray= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Data")) || [];
    dataArray.push(dataFormObjt);
    localStorage.setItem("Data",JSON.stringify(dataArray));
  } 
});
function insertDataTable(dataFormObjt) {
  let tbody = document.querySelector("tbody");
  let row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.insertCell(0).textContent = dataFormObjt["nombre"];
  row.insertCell(1).textContent = dataFormObjt["apellido"];
  row.insertCell(2).textContent = dataFormObjt["edad"];
  row.insertCell(3).textContent = dataFormObjt["fecha"];
  tbody.appendChild(row);
} ```
````

Comment: Falta información para poder ayudarte, en este tipo de casos donde tu código es dependiente de un html que arma la estructura y envía los datos, te conviene pasar el código de ambos, así se pueden hacer pruebas para encontrar una solución lo más rápido posible.

Comment: Esto trozo no lo cierras bien:  `DatosDelLocalStorage.forEach(function(arrayData){
    insertDataTable(arrayData);
  }`... te falta el cierre del forEach, o sea, un parentesis final `)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré el problema. Lo que provocaba que no encuentre coincidencias en Data Tables era provocado por `event.preventDefault();`. Se ve que al dejar que la página siga con su flujo normal, Data Table pudo encontrar resultados para los elementos recién ingresados.